# Search Exactly in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

Thanks for reading this question .

I am using Solr as Search Engine in my application.

When user searchs with "java design patterns". We want Solr returns documents contain exactly "java design patterns" and not "design patterns java" or "java patterns design"...Terms in document are indexed : "design", "patterns", "java" ... other terms.

How can I implement this ?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You would need to check on [SpanNearQuery](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/) which will help to set the terms to be in the same order as being search for.

> A SpanNearQuery will look to find a number of SpanQuerys within a
>   given distance from each other. You can specify that the spans must
>   come in the order specified, or that order should not be considered.
>   These SpanQuerys could be any number of TermQuerys, other
>   SpanNearQuerys, or one of the other SpanQuerys mentioned below. You
>   can nest arbitrarily, eg SpanNearQuerys can contain other
>   SpanNearQuerys that contain still other SpanNearQuerys, etc.

There is a [SurroundQueryParser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SurroundQueryParser) which can help you create these queries, but its not been released yet.

You can create a new Parser by modifing the Dismax OR Edismax Parsers to Create the Span queries, instead of Phrase Queries, with 0 slop.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you very much for replying.This is my code . SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
  solrQuery.setQuery(processedQuery);
  solrQuery.setParam("pf", "search");
  solrQuery.setParam("ps", "10");
  solrQuery.setParam("qs", "10"); . It seem ps and qs are not effect. I used SolrJ. How can I  use SpanNearQuery or  SurroundQueryParser as you answer ?

Comment: Hi, it is : <fieldType name="search_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PhraseQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html). Sending queries between double quotes will return you the exactly matched results.

There is also a question in the Solr FAQ page, which explains [How to search one term near another.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_search_for_one_term_near_another_term_.28say.2C_.22batman.22_and_.22movie.22.29)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I used double quotes, it look like http://180.148.135.72/solr/frontend/select?q=search:"java design patterns". But it returns all documents which contain all of them "java","design","patterns". I read "How to search one term near another", but http://180.148.135.72/solr/frontend/select?q=search:"java design patterns"~10&qs=10 is not effect

Comment: Can you plz show how you index the field in the schema.xml file?

Comment: Hi, it is <fieldType name="search_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that spaces should replaces with\ to avoid it

**Example**:
if we search with `typeOfChange:*Cavity Ids*`  (it will not return anything)
but if we use the `pattern typeOfChange:*Cavity\ Ids*` (it will return data)

What can help is:

```
ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(value.toString())
```

And It's **implementation**:

```
 public static String escapeQueryChars(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char c = s.charAt(i);
      // These characters are part of the query syntax and must be escaped
      if (c == '\\' || c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '!'  || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == ':'
        || c == '^' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c == '\"' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '~'
        || c == '*' || c == '?' || c == '|' || c == '&'  || c == ';' || c == '/'
        || Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
        sb.append('\\');
      }
      sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```